# Webhooks are not fired. API nexmo

Tags: vonage

I use the nexmo api to redirect all call to a virtual us number to a real number.

To implement i use this request : 
https://developer.nexmo.com/api/developer/numbers#update-a-number

With params below:

1. moHttpUrl : an url (https) on my server which respond 200 OK
2. country : US
3. misdn : the us virtual number
4. voiceCallbackType : tel
5. voiceCallbackValue : the real forward
6. voiceStatusCallback : an url (https) on my server which respond 200 OK

(The data is well recorded, i can see it on nexmo backoffice)

Problem : when i call the us number with my phone, the redirection is ok. I stay on line 10 seconds and stop the call.

At the moment nexmo should call my voiceStatusCallback but do nothing. 
Furthermore i have no idea on which informations are passing with the webhook.

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is related to https, the simple call forwarding is part of our deprecated voice API and as such that only supports SHA-1 certs on https, so I'm imagining this is your problem.
https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005461928

There are 2 options, either use http for your callback (not great I know) or take a look at our new Voice API which will give you a lot more control, if you want to do a simple call forward you would just need to host a JSON file on a URL somewhere that contains a connect action see https://developer.nexmo.com/api/voice/ncco#connect You will then get a whole bunch of call event webhooks such as when the call starts, is answered and ends.

Rgds
Sam
Nexmo Developer Advocate

Comment: Thx Sam, 

Set the webhook in http work great !. 

Ome more question it's possible to redirect sms also using ncco ?